# android chat listview with user profile picture

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

I have to implement a chat in android which should look like in the following image:

[image]

How to implement such a ui using listview and adapter?
The row_layout should contain only one message or all messages of one user including his avatar?
Think it should contain only one message, but where to inflate the profile picture for each user at the top of his messages?

Pease help with any suggestions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably, I'd rethink the UI and use an `ExpandableListView`, instead: in the `groups` I'd put the profile picture and the date, in the group `children`, all the messages from that user in that date.

Comment: It's an idea, but the profile picture should be aligned to left/right of messages (smth like float in css)

Comment: Easy. Put the image as a **compound drawable** inside the TextView. You decide where to put it left/right depending on the user/date

Comment: Yes, but the second message then will not be aligned to left of the picture

Comment: Each group can have a different compound drawable. One has it on the right side and the other one has it in the left. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int)

Comment: I mean the second message of the same user

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear: The picture is only set ONCE, on the `Group`, close to the date. All the messages are the `Children` of that group. So, the messages for a user are grouped by a header, under the same date and picture.

Comment: Right, **under** the same date and picture. But I want them to be to left/right of the **picture**. Maybe I'm not clear((

Comment: Well, I proposed you to `rethink the UI`. That's what **I** would do.

Comment: Well, the client decides how should the ui look like(. If you can't do it then he will find another developer ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need two layout for this,both consists from an `ImageView` and a `ListView`. The only difference between them will be the Gravity( one is Left the Other is Right). And in your out most `ListView`'s `getView` method, return this two layout based on the data you have.